# Why is the first one an infinite loop?

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I'm confused.. After it prints the first c, which is 1, then c became 2 then it's supposed to print c, which is 2.. 
    int c = 1;

```
while (c<=10)
    printf("%d\n", c);
    c = c + 1;   

while (c<=10)
{
    printf("%d\n", c);
    c = c + 1;
}
```

Comment: Missing `{}` around `printf("%d\n", c); c = c + 1;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a While loop isn't followed by

```
{
}
```

The next statement is considered only to be part of the loop 
So your code runs the while loop indefinitely printing value of c since the condition for the while loop to run is always true
  enclose the print and increment statement in curly braces!

Comment: Next *statement*, not *line*. The body of a loop is always one statement -- it's just that that statement is usually a compound statement, i.e. several statements wrapped in `{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are no curly braces around the indented block, so only the `printf` is part of the while.

Answer (score 0):

For while loop without the brace it takes single statement after the while loop.

So in the first while loop, the while takes only the printf statement.

If it is enclosed in braces, it takes that as a block of statement. If it is not enclosed in braces it takes only one statement.

So, it will not increase the value of C.

Answer (score 0):

It is because if you dont use {} The while applis only on the first line, that was you have something like

```
while (c<=10)
    printf("%d\n", c);
```

c never changes and the loop runs forever

Answer (score 0):

You are only looping over the print statement and the variable is not getting incremented.

```
c = c + 1;
```

Is not called. The `{ }` define the scope of the while loop not the tab character.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
while (c<=10)
printf("%d\n", c);
c = c + 1;
```

to:

```
while (c<=10){
    printf("%d\n", c);
    c = c + 1;   
}
```

The reason is that if there is no brackets after while, then only the first instruction right after it is executed.